# invalid operation: connot index static[] (value of type byte)

Tags: go, environment-variables, byte

When trying to change the static content information set in the toml file to one using environment variables error question that occurred

Put the corresponding code first

```
// .env variables
STATICS=[["web", "/var/www/ichain-admin-react"],["static", "static"]]


// source code
func serveStaticFiles(engine *gin.Engine) {
    statics := os.Getenv("STATICS")
    for i := 0; i < len(statics); i++ {
        url, root := statics[i][0], statics[i][1]

        if !path.IsAbs(root) {
            root = path.Join(config.ExecutedPath, root)
        }
        engine.Static(url, root)
    }
}
```

```
invalid operation: cannot index statics[i] (value of type byte)
```

I didn't find any articles that would help me much

Thank you

Comment: The return value of the os.Getenv is a string https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Getenv so is not indexable in this way.

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You can't index a `byte` type.  `statics` is a string. You index it with `statics[i]`, then you have a single byte. But then you're trying to index it again. You can't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`os.Getenv`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Getenv) returns a `string` which you can't index in the way you're trying to. But since the value has the same format as a json array of arrays, you should be able to use the `encoding/json` package to parse the string and decode it into a Go slice.

Something like this should work:

```
func serveStaticFiles(engine *gin.Engine) {
    statics := os.Getenv("STATICS")

    slice := [][]string{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(statics), &slice); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for i := 0; i < len(slice); i++ {
        url, root := slice[i][0], slice[i][1]

        if !path.IsAbs(root) {
            root = path.Join(config.ExecutedPath, root)
        }
        engine.Static(url, root)
    }
}
```